# Managing associated partners involved in opportunities

Tags: opportunity

We have complex opportunities that involve many outside companies. It seems like if another account is used, this clutters up our accounts. Contacts doesn't seem appropriate since these are not individuals.

Is there some other business partner or associate entity that I am missing? What is the best way to handle this? Also, there will need to be multiple entries that need to have their role in the opportunity identified.

Comment: Have you established Partner Roles, Opportunity Roles, Opportunity Teams, and Opportunity Splits?

Comment: @crmprogdev - Opportunity roles are contacts and not compaies. Partner Roles are no longer available, Opportunity teams just let multiple members access the same record. I just want to be able to indicate some outside entity/company as being involved in the deal. Example: Investment Banker = ABC Bank.

Comment: Perhaps I should have asked what you've tried. I show Partner Roles as being active in my Dev Org and in the Object Reference. One can have Opportunity Partners as well which is what I meant to write when I asked about Opp Teams.

Answer (score 1):

Out of the box, SFDC includes a `Partner` SObject that can be used between

- Two Accounts
- An Opportunity and an Account

Having the SObject `Account` represent partners on an Opportunity is not unusual. You differentiate "customer" Accounts from "partner" Accounts by either recordTypes or other custom field.  Note that it would not be unusual at all for a "partner" on an Opportunity also being a "customer" on some other opportunity. Using Account as the single SObject for both partners and customers aids in reporting

As the OOB Partner object can't be customized, you might want to have your own junction SObject between Opportunity and Account

N.B.  Partner Roles are still available (see Account and Opportunity Setup); Partner Portal is no longer available in orgs created Summer13 or later (replaced by Communities)

Comment: Do you find users get confused with the partner and customer accounts?

Comment: So I could associate multiple partner accounts to a single customer account?

Comment: (1) Confusion betw partner and customer accounts - Not really, typically there is some 'type' field on the Account that differentiates customers from partners. Such 'type' field could be part of the Lookup search field results ; (2) Yep - Multiple partner accounts can be associated to one Customer account; One partner account can be associated to multiple customer Accounts